# Placing the proper pronoun at the end of a sentence

Tags: grammar

I was reading the *Grammar for Dummies* book by Geraldine Woods, and in page 24, under the *Placing the Proper Pronoun in the Proper Place* section, the author stated the following:

> The pronoun you put after a linking verb should be the same kind of
> pronoun that you put before a linking verb.

She gave a few examples, and an analysis:

> - *The winner of the election is him!*
> - *Him is the winner of the election!*
>
> Uh oh. Something's wrong. You don't say *him is*, unless you're in an
> old Tarzan movie. You say *he is*. Because you have a linking verb
> (is), you must put the same word after the linking verb that you would
> put before the linking verb. Try it again:
>
> - *The winner of the election is *he*!*
> - **He* is the winner of the election!*
>
> Now you've got the correct ending for your sentence.

The third example, "The winner of the election is he!", sounds a bit weird to me. Shouldn't you use *him* instead? Or ... perhaps I just misinterpreted here?

Comment: Not all books on grammar are gospel, asdf.

Comment: This book is teaching you 19th century grammar. In 21st century grammar, you put the objective case after the linking verb. Language changes.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I am not saying it is, nor do I treat it like one. I was simply perplexed. My instincts says the opposite of what the book is saying. I can't possibly know which one is "correct." That's why I asked here. 

Apologies for any grammar errors.

Comment: There is a list of recommended grammars (ie books on grammar) in the [resources thread](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available) on ELU.Meta. _Grammar for Dummies_ and _Strunk and White_ are not mentioned. Some of McCawley is available online, but the other great works are extremely expensive. All these are demanding. 'Intermediate Level' grammar is usually well addressed, in a balanced way, by Professor Nordquist, at ThoughtCo.